# How to fix the bug with freezing NPC animations and doors?

Tags: hp-prisoner-of-azkaban

In the third Harry Potter game, "Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban" for PC, when Ron goes into the first lesson and meets an imp which is supposed to start throwing candy at you, after the cut-scene plays the imp freezes and does nothing. Even if I get a game save and try to continue after that moment, farther into the game there are still similar problems with picture doors which also freeze.

I've seen people post about this problem on forums ever since the game was released in 2004 but there is no solution. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Me and my friend also encountered this problem today while playing in windowed mode for sharing screen via Skype. To fix this, toggle between fullscreen and windowed mode by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> until the animation resumes as it should. If it doesn't work right away, try loading the game before the animation freezes and play it in fullscreen mode. Then you may resume playing in windowed mode.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is a bit late... but I figured out how to get past this... in your installation folder of the game, go to the DEFUSER.ini file, it is a file for changing keystrokes in the game, then search for backspace, and type next to it Ghost, it will be backspace=ghost, also change another button, say button B, to walk, B=walk, then while in game and the imp is frozen, hit the backspace button to activate ghost mode, fly through the roof, and hit button b to activate walk mode again, and you can continue from there without problem

Comment: This is what worked.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late probably but for anyone who hasn't got this fixed yet, this worked for me. A combination of what others have suggested:

- Find the folder where HP3 is installed. Mine is at `C:\Program Files (x86)\EA Games\Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban(TM)`.
- Go into the `System` folder, and find the `Default.ini` file.
- Copy it elsewhere, like on your desktop, for a backup in case something goes wrong when you edit it.
- Right click on the Default.ini file that is still in the System folder (not the copy you just made), click Properties, then the the Security tab. Click Edit to change permissions. Click on the group or user name in the box, then tick the box next Full Control under Allow. This will give you administrative permission to amend the Default.ini file and will stop the error message when trying to save it later. Click Apply, then OK.
- Next double click the Default.ini file in the System folder and it should open with Notepad or a similar text editor. If it asks what to open it with, choose Notepad.
- Scroll down to about 3/4 of the way down, and find the section headed `[D3DDrv.D3DRenderDevice]`. If you search, it will probably be the 2nd entry you find, not the first one. Under the heading [D3DDrv.D3DRenderDevice], scroll down a little until you find this line: `ReduceMouseLag=True` ... delete the word *True* and replace it with `False` and save the document.

The second thing is compatibility. Right click on the desktop shortcut icon of HP3, and click Properties. Click the Compatibility tab at the top. Tick the boxes for:

- Run this program in compatibility mode for Windows XP (Service Pack 2)
- Run in 640x480 screen resolution
- Run this program as an administrator.

Click Apply, then OK. Then just double click the game shortcut icon to start the game as normal. These things fixed this for me.

*Note: I wrote it out in so much detail for the users who might need it explained in detail. Don't leave out the run in 640x480 screen resolution because it is necessary.*

Comment: We tried this and unfortunately it did not work for us.

Answer (score 1):

`[D3DDrv.D3DRenderDevice]` - type that in search, click HPPOA, scroll to that line in text that comes up,change each line as below, play in safe mode (configsys) to save past imps, restart in regular boot. Play.

```
DetailTextures=False
HighDetailActors=False
SuperHighDetailActors=False
UsePrecaching=True
UseTrilinear=False
AdapterNumber=-1
ReduceMouseLag=False
UseTripleBuffering=False
UseHardwareTL=True
UseHardwareVS=True
UseCubemaps=False
DesiredRefreshRate=75
UseCompressedLightmaps=True
UseStencil=True
Use16bit=False
Use16bitTextures=False
MaxPixelShaderVersion=255
UseVSync=False
```